# PHP compare two text files by lines

Tags: php, file

I need to compare two language files - English and German. Each text file has one word/phrase per line. Word/phrase [x] in first language is word/phrase [x] in second language. The translated word is on the same line in the second file.

I tried to get the translation using the following code, but it seems that the loop does not work. I always get "none". Any ideas?

```
function translation($word,$service,$sprache1,$sprache2){
$typus ="transl";
$mypath = "data/".$service."/";

mkdir($mypath,0777,TRUE);

//fh - First language file
$myFile = $mypath."".$typus."-".$sprache1.".txt";
$fh = file($myFile) or die("can't open file");

//fh2 - Second language file

$myFile2 = $mypath."".$typus."-".$sprache2.".txt";
$fh2 = file($myFile2) or die("can't open file");


$x=0;
$result = "none";
foreach ($fh as $line) {


        if (stripos($word,$line))
        {$result = $fh2[$x];
        break;
        } 

$x=$x+1;

            }

return $result;                                                         
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `$result` is always "none"?

Comment: Yes, the function returns the value that was defined before the loop.

Comment: Do you know that `stripos` can return both **0** and **false**, and they have different meanings?

Comment: You have two issues that you should solve before implementing any answer from this thread: If you really read the file completely from disk for every string you have to translate, that's quite some overhead. And furthermore, don't you think that "translating" the word `cat` should only work if `cat` is in the translation file, and should fail if only `muscat` and `cathedral` are in the translation file?

Comment: You might try looking at using a [_dictionary_](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Read the files into a hash table/dictionary so that the key is one language and the value the other. That way you don't need a for loop and can just check if dictionary[$word] is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is in wrong `if` statement.
The point is that `stripos` (like `strpos`) can return **0** or **false** as a result.

For example if you search for 'cat' in a word 'cats' `stripos` will return **0**, as it's the first position of cat-string.
On the other side, if you search 'dog' in a word 'cats' `stripos` will return **false** as nothing is found.

So in you function the `if` case should be more strict:

```
if (stripos($word,$line) !== false)
```

This means that your word is found even if it starts from position 0.
You current `if` statement doesn't allow **0** (zero) value to be accepted.

Comment: Your previous answer     $fh = file($myFile,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) has solved the problem. Thank you so much! To be sure I also modified the "if" case. After that I had the problem that the function returned nothing for some word, but this was caused by different text file encoding - ANSI and UTF-8. Now all is working! Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code I found 2 different problems.

First of all, be careful with [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). This function returns `0` if the `$needle` is found at the beginning (i.e. position 0), and `false` if the `$needle` was not found. In PHP, `0` is eval'd to `false` by default.
You should change your `if` statement to:

```
if(stripos($word, $line) !== false)
```

Note the [`!==`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator, which is stronger than `!=`.

The second and most important problem, which prevents your function from working, is that you compare lines which can contains invisible characters (e.g. "[newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)" chars). You should trim the strings before comparing them.
I'd change your `if` statement for:

```
if(trim($word) === trim($line))
```

which is simpler. Or if you really want to keep `stripos`:

```
if(stripos(trim($word), trim($line)) !== false)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use the trim function.